# Finding a case in which the dominated converge theorem doesn't hold when ignoring it's assumptions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

A exercise in a measure textbook I own asks: Give an example to show that the conclusion of the dominated convergence theorem
(DCT) may cease to hold if we drop the domination assumption even if we additionally assume that $µ(X) < ∞.$ I'm unsure of how to find this result, here is what I've found so far:

The assumption in the DCT states there is an integrable $g: X→\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n(x)|≤g(x)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N},$ hence without this we could say $|f_n(x)|= ∞$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ With this knowledge if I say $f_n(x)=1_X\frac n{n-1}$ then $\lim_{n\to ∞}\int_Xf_n(x)dμ=\int_X1_Xdμ$ which satisfies the theorem as $\lim_{n\to∞}f_n(x)=f(x)=1_X$? I'm confused as to what I've done wrong and what I could do to get the result the exercise is requesting, if I'm not on the right track here where would be a better place to start? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a condition on $g.$

Comment: What you "done wrong" is to claim "without this we could say |f$_n$(x)|= ∞ for some  n$\in$$\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: The basic example is $X=[0,1]$ $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n&x\in(0,1/n)\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Then $f_n\to 0$ but $\int f_n=1$ for all $n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm afraid not, that is a similar question however it doesn't answer the question I'm asking

Comment: Read it more carefully. Btw, its counterexample is the same as Thomas Andrews comment above.

Comment: @AnneBauval You're right they are pretty much the same, thank you. My only concern is the result that f$_n$ approaches zero? Is that deduced as the bound of x approaches a μ-null set?

Comment: Yes, as shown by the OP in the duplicate for *almost everywhere* ("a.e.") convergence. Thomas Andrews'example above is nicer because it converges *everywhere*.

Comment: @AnneBauval ah I understand that makes perfect sense, thank you. I understand Thomas said I need a condition on g however I'm still confused about the g that the exercise refers to, why does the
sequence that we have found not have an integrable majorant?

Comment: @AnneBauval My apologies, I meant the f$_n$ that Thomas Andrews found, I've discarded where I started as I wasn't on the right track to prove the result. Surely by the same logic doesn't our sequence have an integrable majorant as we just found it to approach zero?

Comment: Right, the DCT proves that $(|f_n|)$ has no integrable majorant, since $\lim\int f_n\ne\int\lim f_n.$ You can also prove it directly: the integral of its lub is the harmonic series.

Comment: You should identify the textbook that motivates your Question.  If it is one I'm thinking of, your requested example is already given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition for how you can fail to have convergence of integrals when you do have a.e. convergence is either "compressing an area down to a null set" or "moving an area to infinity". In either of these cases you can have a.e. convergence to zero without the integrals going to zero. The latter is impossible with a finite measure space, but the former is still possible.